# Can I make a video player with PySimpleGUI?

Tags: user-interface, video, video-player, pysimplegui

I'm trying to make a video player showing subtitle text and some other information. I've learnt some basic stuffs about PySimpleGUI but I did not find any material talking about video player in this module. Does PySimpleGUI actually have such a function?

Comment: try https://github.com/israel-dryer/Media-Player